# Date selector in html form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a field in my html/bootstrap form so that a date can be selected from the calendar. Can someone help with some example code?

Comment: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Html5 date input

```
<input type="date" name="name">
```

that will show the browser datepicker and if you prefer to use a plugin try that [bootstrap date picker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)